# Limesurvey - setting token attributes from responses

Tags: javascript, php, limesurvey

I know i can add attributes to token table and use them to pre-populate questions with answers. for eg {TOKEN:ATTRIBUTE_5}
I would like to know if i can do the same vice-versa i.e

I want to set the response of  a question to a token attribute.

how can i do that?

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the token is set for data available before the participant responds.
As so, I would wonder, why you need to have that data on the token instead of catching it directly from the response?

If that is a must, I would suggest to develop a script which runs after the survey ends. There are multiple ways of doing that: A plugin, API, DB...

Hope my answer was helpfull. We can follow up if you feel like.

Answer (score 0):

Use this plugin : https://framagit.org/SondagePro-LimeSurvey-plugin/updateTokenByResponse

It's done for this, licence : Affero GPL